# How to suppress warning messages from cast()

Tags: r, reshape

I use `cast()` from the `reshape` package quite frequently. Almost every time, this warning pops up:

`Aggregation requires fun.aggregate: length used as default`

I've tried to set `options( warn =-1)`, to no avail. How does one suppress these warnings?

Comment: I think the reason `options("warn")` has no effect is that that is actually generated by `message` not `warning`. `suppressMessages` may work, but I don't know of a way to do that globally.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could manually specify fun.aggregate to be length.

```
cast(your_inputs_to_cast, fun.aggregate = length)
```

Answer (score 11):

`Aggregation requires fun.aggregate: length used as default`

is `message` not a `warning` - letting you know  that the function as decided something for you. I think the best option is @Dason's answer - i.e. to manually specify this option.

However, If you don't want to do that:

You can suppress messages by wrapping the function in `suppressMessages`

Using the example from `cast`

```
names(ChickWeight) <- tolower(names(ChickWeight))
chick_m <- melt(ChickWeight, id=2:4, na.rm=TRUE)

suppressMessages(cast(chick_m, time ~ variable))
```

Or you could create your own function

```
cast_suppress <- function(...){suppressMessages(cast(...))}
cast_suppress(chick_m, time ~ variable)
```